# laravel 5.6 throws laravel-mix error on VPS

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, npm, laravel-mix

There's no laravel-mix folder in node_modules
help me!
[image: error laravel mix]

Comment: run `npm install`

Comment: i have run npm install, but it error above

Comment: Did you use npm or yarn?

Comment: delete `node_modules` and run `npm install` again.

Comment: thank you, i have install succesfuly